# Reading a file and converting the input into two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, file

I want to read a file containing numbers in two columns.

```
1   2 
3   4
5   6
7   8
```

I want to place the numbers in the first column into one array, and the ones in the second column into another array. Both of these arrays will always have the same amount of elements. The maximum number of elements permitted in this program is 100.

Here's what I have so far. This just reads in the elements as regular int and prints them out.

```
while (!feof (filereader))
{  
  printf ("%d %d\n",col_one,col_two);
  fscanf (filereader, "%d %d", &col_one, &col_two);      
}
```

So how do I place the numbers in the first column from the file into one array and the numbers in the second column into an array?

Comment: yes, I see the first column

Comment: yes, me too. Is that answer to the question?

Comment: I think you meant to call `scanf` BEFORE printing ?

Comment: firstly printf(); and following scanf(); looks strange to me.

Comment: What is asked? 

"I want to place those numbers (1,3,5,7) into an array. I also want to place the second column with the numbers 2,4,6, and 8 into a separate array" how do I do that? I then plan on doing numerous sorting operations to the array but I know how to do that.

Comment: You are right I do have to call have scanf before printing I was just a dummy and left a scan statement outside the while loop so it actually works.

Comment: The spaces are just to make the output a little more legible. In the file being read in there are no line breaks except a tab between 1 and 2 3 and 4 etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
int array1[100];
int array2[100];
int i, size = 0;

while (size<100 && fscanf (filereader, " %d %d", &array1[size], &array2[size])==2)
{  
     size++;
}

for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
   printf("array1[%d] = %d,  array2[%d] = %d\n",
          i, array1[i], i, array2[i]);
}
```

add space at the beginning of the format specifier of scanf  `" %d %d"` this will avoid the problem of newlines in your file

Comment: That's odd. It compiles but crashes immediately after running. Let me try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @KINGKONGYOUHEARMEFORYASEEME I tested it and it works for me without problems. Just I fixed the order of variables in the printf

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got a maximum size, it's pretty easy. Just define the arrays like so:

```
int firstArray[100];
int secondArray[100];
int size = 0;
```

Then do your loop, incrementing the index for each line:

```
while (!feof (filereader))
{  
     fscanf (filereader, "%d %d", &col_one, &col_two);
     firstArray[size] = col_one;
     secondArray[size] = col_two;
     size++;
}
```

Maybe also think about making sure `size < 100` in case the file is too long.